# Cant do redirect (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to do redirect to controller

Here is my controller

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string question1, string question2, string question3, string question4, string question5, string question6, string question7, string question8, string question9, string question10, Int32 id)
        {
            QuestionBlock question = new QuestionBlock
            {
                Question1 = question1,
                Question2 = question2,
                Question3 = question3,
                Question4 = question4,
                Question5 = question5,
                Question6 = question6,
                Question7 = question7,
                Question8 = question8,
                Question9 = question9,
                Question10 = question10,
                Interview_Id = id,
            };

            //TempData["id"] = id;
            db.QuestionBlocks.Add(question);
            db.SaveChanges();

             return Json(new { Result = "Success", Message = "Saved Successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


I try to do it like this

     return RedirectToAction("Index", "Questions", new { id = id });
```

I have this AJAX call in my View. Maybe trouble in it?

```
<script>
    $('.click').on('click', function () {
        $('.content').toggle();
    });
    var counter = 0;
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#save').click(function () {
            save();
        });
    });
    function save()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'Post',
            dataType: 'Json',
            data: {
                     question1: $('#Question1').val(),
                     question2: $('#Question2').val(),
                     question3: $('#Question3').val(),
                     question4: $('#Question4').val(),
                     question5: $('#Question5').val(),
                     question6: $('#Question6').val(),
                     question7: $('#Question7').val(),
                     question8: $('#Question8').val(),
                     question9: $('#Question9').val(),
                     question10: $('#Question10').val(),

            },
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Questions")',
            success: function (da) {
                if (da.Result === "Success") {

                        alert('Вопросы сохранены');




                } else {

                    alert( 'Error'+ da.Message);
                }
            },
            error: function (da) {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
}

</script>
```

But redirection not works. Where is my trouble?

Maybe I need to do it not in controller?

Thank's for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is returning a JSON response with 2 properties and your main view code is making an ajax call to this action method. So the JSON response returned from the action method will be handled in the `success` handler of your ajax call. It will not do a redirect unless you explicitly do so.

Even if you replace the `return Json` with `return RedirectToAction`, It does not makes sense to use it with the Ajax call. The whole idea of ajaxifying the page is to avoid the traditional page submit - reload experience and replace it with partial page upload behavior (*better user experience*)

If you absolutely want to redirect to another page, you can do that in the `success` event handler. But like i mentioned earlier, it does not makes sense to do an ajax post then. Do a normal form post!

```
if (da.Result === "Success") {
   window.location.href="Give the new Url you want to navigate to here";
}
```

You can use the UrlHelper class to generate the correct url to the other action method and send that as part of your JSON response.

```
var urlBuilder = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext);
var url = urlBuilder.Action("Index", "Questions",new { id= id});
return Json(new { Result = "Success", Message = "Saved Successfully",RedirectUrl=url });
```

Now in your ajax call , read the `RedirectUrl` property

```
if (da.Result === "Success") {
   window.location.href=da.RedirectUrl;
}
```

Comment: But I need to return value when do redirect.
Like this `new { id = id }`

Comment: Your action method has a parameter for the `id`. That means you need to use send that value from your client side code ajax code. You can use it.  You can use the `UrlHelper` class to build the url in server and return that as part of your JSON response and use that.

Comment: See the updated answer which includes code to generate the url in server and send that as part of JSON response

Comment: Will try this now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just like this without writing Questions.:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = yourvalue });
```

EDIT:

Otherwise you can try this:

```
return RedirectToAction( "Index", new RouteValueDictionary( 
new { controller = controllerName, action = "Index", id = id } ) );
```

Comment: You mean, without AJAX call?

Comment: Try to edit your RedirectToAction to one of the two examples I gave you. I don't think your AJAX call is causing problems.

Comment: Will try now your solution